# How to install Calendar functions for PHP 7.4 on CentOS?

Tags: php, calendar

I updated a Linux server to PHP 7.4 and now the calendar functions aren't working:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function cal_days_in_month()

How do I install the Calendar functions for PHP 7.4?

I have root access and am running CentOS 7.

Comment: To get these functions to work, you have to compile PHP with --enable-calendar.

Comment: The easiest way would be to use the same procedure you used to install core PHP (yum repo, compile from source, whatever).